# Dijktra's-How to keep track of nodes in the shortest path from source to the target

Tags: c++, dijkstra

Yesterday I studied Dijktra's algorithm to find the shortest path.I tried few problems on it so that I can have some command over it.But I faced this question **in which it is asked to find the nodes in the shortest path from source to target if their is path from source to target else print "Impossible"**.Even after thinking a lot I could not manage to solve this problem.Can anybody help ?

Comment: If you have thought a lot about it, you must have some ideas. Bring them. Also you tagged this as "C++". Do you have some code?

Comment: @Mads See i might sound completely rubbish but the best I thought was to keep maintain  a vector.

Answer (score 0):

**Djikstra's algorithm** might seem conceptually **easy to understand**, but it requires quite an effort to **implement**. You require a data structure such as a **Priority queue** to efficiently store and retrieve the nodes with the lowest weight. This algorithm is BFS derivative with greedy algorithm concepts.

I have used the **C++ STL Set datastructure** instead of priority queue to store the nodes with minimum weights  (check this for set data structure details http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/set/).

Bear in mind that this code only works for edges with positive weights. *For edges with negative weights, you'll need to learn **Bellman-Ford algorithm***.

**PROGRAM CODE:**

```
#include<set>
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib>
#include<vector>
#define INF 9999999

using namespace std;

struct vw{
    int index;
    bool visited=false;
    int w=INF;
};
int adj[10][10], v, e, visited[10];

class comparisonClass{
public:
    bool operator()(struct vw a, struct vw b){
        return (a.w < b.w);
    }
};

int main(){
    cin>>v>>e;                              
    // Enter the number of edges & vertices.
    struct vw *vertex = new struct vw[v];
    for(int i=0; i<e; i++){
        char a, b;                          
        int w;
        cin>>a>>b>>w;                       
        // Enter egde and weights: Eg- A B 5  B D 20
        cout<<a<<" "<<b<<" "<<w<<endl;
        adj[a-65][b-65]=adj[b-65][a-65]=w;
        vertex[i].index=i;
    }
    set<struct vw, comparisonClass> weightList;
    vertex[0].w=0;  vertex[0].visited=true;
    weightList.insert(vertex[0]);

    while(!weightList.empty()){
        struct vw source = *(weightList.begin());
        weightList.erase(weightList.begin());
        int ind = source.index;
        source.visited=true;

        for(int i=0; i<v; i++){
            if(adj[ind][i] && vertex[i].visited==false)
                if(adj[ind][i]+source.w < vertex[i].w){
                    vertex[i].w = adj[ind][i] + source.w;
                    weightList.insert(vertex[i]);
                }
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i<v; i++)
        cout<<"\nA to "<<(char)(65+i)<<" cost="<<vertex[i].w<<endl; 
        // Printed results in format of Edges and least weight, Eg- A to D cost = 12.
    delete[]vertex;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

It's very easy, look at [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm) there is Pseudocode

```
 1  function Dijkstra(Graph, source):
 2
 3      dist[source] ← 0                       // Distance from source to source
 4      prev[source] ← undefined               // Previous node in optimal path initialization
 5
 6      for each vertex v in Graph:  // Initialization
 7          if v ≠ source            // Where v has not yet been removed from Q (unvisited nodes)
 8              dist[v] ← infinity             // Unknown distance function from source to v
 9              prev[v] ← undefined            // Previous node in optimal path from source
10          end if 
11          add v to Q                     // All nodes initially in Q (unvisited nodes)
12      end for
13      
14      while Q is not empty:
15          u ← vertex in Q with min dist[u]  // Source node in first case
16          remove u from Q 
17          
18          for each neighbor v of u:           // where v is still in Q.
19              alt ← dist[u] + length(u, v)
20              if alt < dist[v]:               // A shorter path to v has been found
21                  dist[v] ← alt 
22                  prev[v] ← u 
23              end if
24          end for
25      end while
26
27      return dist[], prev[]
28
29  end function
```

*If we are only interested in a shortest path between vertices source and target, we can terminate the search after line 15 if u = target. Now we can read the shortest path from source to target by reverse iteration:*

```
1  S ← empty sequence
2  u ← target
3  while prev[u] is defined:                 // Construct the shortest path with a stack S
4      insert u at the beginning of S          // Push the vertex onto the stack
5      u ← prev[u]                             // Traverse from target to source
6  end while
```